# How to configure group attributes for strongswan EAP-radius with freeradius mysql

Tags: strongswan, freeradius

so I am trying to figure out how to link up the usage of Groups in Strongswan with Freeradius using SQL (plus daloradius)

Currently the authentication between Strongswan and Freeradius is working fine. However, I would like to have groups so to separate different connections. However I am getting stuck at how to map the group. Basically I have created General and EPD

here is the ipsec.conf

```
conn %default
       compress = yes
       dpdaction = clear
       dpddelay = 30s
       inactivity = 300s
       leftdns = 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1
       rightdns = 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1
       esp = aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!
       ike = aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp$
       keyexchange = ikev2
       keyingtries = 1

conn IKEv2-BASE
       leftca = "C=HK, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
       leftsendcert = always
       rightsendcert = never
       leftcert = server.cert.pem
       left = %any
       right = %any
       leftauth = pubkey
       rightauth = eap-radius
       leftfirewall = yes
       leftsubnet = 0.0.0.0/0
       fragmentation = yes
       eap_identity = %any
       rekey = no

conn test1
       also = IKEv2-BASE
       leftid = ip1
       rightsourceip = 10.1.0.0/16
       rightgroups = "General"
       auto = add

conn test2
       also = IKEv2-BASE
       leftid = ip1
       rightsourceip = 10.2.0.0/16
       rightgroups = "EPD"
       auto = add
```

in the database, I can see my user already have added into the group.
this is the error message shown

````
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] no alternative config found
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] selected peer config 'EPD' unacceptable: non-matching authentication done
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] constraint check failed: group membership to 'EPD' required
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] switching to peer config 'EPD'
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] selected peer config 'General' unacceptable: non-matching authentication done
Oct 5 06:30:38 vm_strongswanikev2 charon: 14[CFG] constraint check failed: group membership to 'General' required```

Looking at the log it seems it cannot read the group attribute from the database, what else do I need to turn on / map at the file? it seems even right now I run radtest, it will not show me any group attributes

Thank you so much for your help first
````

Comment: The RADIUS server has to send the group name as `class` attribute in the Access-Accept message. Make sure you configured FreeRADIUS to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if your users have Groups. I think for you need just enable class(your groups in Radius DB) in  /etc/strongswan.conf

```
    charon {
     ....
      plugins {
        include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
        eap-radius {
          class_group = yes
....
```

i.e. see parameter **class_group = yes**

see more detail https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/rw-eap-md5-class-radius/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).